# Issues in creating CSS image gallery

Tags: css, html-table

Here is my [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uL6t9/)

I am new to CSS. I am trying to create an image gallery. I designed the layout using `table` `tr` `td` tag.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="gallery">
  <table>
<tr>
  <td> <img class="normalimage" src=""> </td>
  <td> <img class="wideimage" src=""> </td>
  <td> <img class="normalimage" src=""> </td>
  <td> <img class="normalimage" src=""> </td>
  <td> <img class="wideimage" src=""> </td>
  <td> <img class="normalimage" src=""> </td>
  <td> <img class="normalimage" src=""> </td>
  <td> <img class="wideimage" src=""> </td>
  <td> <img class="normalimage" src=""> </td>
  <td> <img class="normalimage" src=""> </td>
  <td> <img class="wideimage" src=""> </td>
  <td> <img class="normalimage" src=""> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td> <img class="normalimage" src=""> </td>
  <td> <img class="normalimage" src=""> </td>
  <td> <img class="wideimage" src=""> </td>
  <td> <img class="normalimage" src=""> </td>
  <td> <img class="normalimage" src=""> </td>
  <td> <img class="wideimage" src=""> </td>
  <td> <img class="normalimage" src=""> </td>
  <td> <img class="normalimage" src=""> </td>
  <td> <img class="wideimage" src=""> </td>
  <td> <img class="normalimage" src=""> </td>
  <td> <img class="normalimage" src=""> </td>
  <td> <img class="wideimage" src=""> </td>
</tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Here is my css:

```
.gallery {
background-color: #abcdef;
width:355px;
height: 265px;
overflow-x: scroll;
}
.gallery img {
display: block;
margin-left: 20px;
margin-top: 20px;
}
.normalimage {
height: 80px;
width: 50px;
border: 5px solid black;
}
.wideimage {
height: 80px;
width: 130px;
border: 5px solid black;
}
```

Question: In the 2nd row I want my third image to appear just after second image with 20px distance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a table here. Just wrap the images in one `<div>` per row like this:

```
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="row">
    <img class="normalimage" src="">
    <!-- more images -->
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <img class="normalimage" src="">
    <!-- more images -->
   </div>
</div>
```

And adjust your CSS like this:

```
.gallery .row {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.gallery img {
    display: inline-block;
    /* other properties */
}
```

[**Example Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/uL6t9/1/)

Comment: i agreed with your way. but can you please let me know what i am doing wrong. and how to correct that.

Comment: @Aadietya Tables are for displaying tabular data. So it is not only sorted rowise, but also columnwise: Values in the same column always appear below each other (unless using something like colspan). So your desired behavior just is in conflict with this and thus you should choose a different structure.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure i understood your question but maybe this is what you want:

Create a class called `newClass`, and a `margin-left` property to it.

Also give a `!important` tag, so the browser knows this has precedence over the other rules.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uL6t9/85/)